# python speed difference between regex vs slicing?

Tags: python, regex

I'm not asking about how to regex the table but why the speed difference is happening

I had a 10gb CSV file and I wanted to find specific value like this.

origin CSV table.

id | value |            date           | num

1  |"12first"|   "dummy val+ 18-10-20" | "92dummy"

to this.

id | value |            date         | num

1  |"first"|        "18-10-20"       | 92

I used pandas library both slicing and regex method and found out that
regex in pandas is really slow compared to slicing the table.
So regex is no silver bullet to every searching optimization right?

Comment: Regex has never been a silver bullet for searching optimization. It's quite slow in almost every use-case, compared to simpler searching that can achieve the same result

Comment: Pandas was developed to be quicker using methods on large data structures. Regex is regex..... https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/

Comment: Regex is only useful in very specific situations. The idea that it is a general purpose tool is very prevalent among beginners on this site, and I really don't know why.

Comment: Ok, I thought Regex was kind of fancy stuff but it was not.  
Thank you for letting me know my ignorance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performing a regex search first compiles a finite state machine, and then runs through it as it looks through the string character by character to see what matches.  If it found a partial match and then came across something that invalidated that match, it has to back up and start again.  Of course, if your regex is simple, there may not be any backtracking, but it's still considering the value of every character at a minimum.

On the other hand, slicing goes to a point and makes a cut.  It doesn't care what the values of the characters are between the points where it is making the cut, it just does it.  This is why fixed width data formats were basically the only way to go when processing cycles were super expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing is straight forward method: go through the data, find a divider, put everything before into a list, continue to the end.

Regular expressions on the other hand can get very complex if they contain wildcards or repetitions. The matcher then has to check many possible combinations of groups for the wildcard if they apply.

They can be very inefficient. Infact some time ago an unluckily combination of wildcards and a lot of spaces brought Stack Overflow to its knees shortly.